# Fail to start HBase in Pseudo-Distributed mode throws "Failed construction RegionServer"

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hbase

I am trying to run HBase pseudo-distributed in a docker image of ubuntu.

After start-hbase.sh, HMaster and RegionServer don't run properly.

Both RegionServer and Master log shows:

```
ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServer: Failed construction RegionServer
java.io.IOException: Couldn't create proxy provider class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxiesClient.createFailoverProxyProvider(NameNodeProxiesClient.java:261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxiesClient.createFailoverProxyProvider(NameNodeProxiesClient.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxiesClient.createProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxiesClient.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3474)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3442)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:524)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem.<init>(HFileSystem.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeFileSystem(HRegionServer.java:763)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:653)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.constructRegionServer(HRegionServer.java:3155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.start(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.run(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.main(HRegionServer.java:3173)
```

jps shows:

```
31168 HQuorumPeer
14801 NodeManager
2049 Jps
12435 SecondaryNameNode
12105 NameNode
14699 ResourceManager
14141 DataNode
```

core-site.xml is :

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/bigdata/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

The hdfs-site.xml shows:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
<value>localhost:50070</value>
</property>
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.hdfscluster</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
</configuration>
```

Both of the config files are soft linked from hadoop/etc/hadoop/
I don't know how to fix this issue base on the log. Thanks for the help!

---

Update:
After fixing the syntax error in hdfs-site.xml pointing out by majid.

```
"ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServer: Failed construction RegionServer
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hdfs
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:448)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxiesClient.createProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxiesClient.java:139)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `hdfs-site.xml` is not in correct format.
It should be:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
    <value>hdfscluster</value>
 </property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
<value>localhost:50070</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.hdfscluster</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Or remove `dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.hdfscluster` property and `hdfs-site.xml` should be

```
<configuration>
   <property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
<value>localhost:50070</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Make sure format namenode before start HBase.

Comment: I tried both ways but the region server still won't start. The log changed slightly. I will update in the question.

Comment: The problem in the question is solved and this is another problem. However, If you use a hostname called hdfs, add it along with IP to your /etc/hosts or just use IP instead of hostnames. Use second config to avoid more problems.

Comment: I will mark this as correct. But I am not sure if hdfs is the hostname since I am running it from docker. I read from somewhere else saying that this is the HA service name,

Comment: first check ip:50070 to see hdfs is running or not. focus on second hdfs-site, in first one you set a config for HA. Forget HA for start. if HDFS is running you can run HBASE.